# Overleaf Link to project appears in the file

Tags: latex, overleaf

I have stumbled across an error in my Latex File. Currently I have a link on every page which leads to the directory of my Latex project. I haven't set this link though and I want it to disappear. It is also visible when I download the PDF.

[image: Picture of the problem]

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay i fixed it but its very embarrassing ... Accidently the link was put into the header of the pages. I don't know how that happened but I solved the error